# How to edit users in ASPNETDB.MDF

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, aspnetdb

Hey I am wondering how I can edit users stored in ASPNETDB.MDF
I am using ASP.Net 4 / Visual Studio / SQL Server.

I can set a gridview to show the users, but cannot directly edit them.
I will be wanting to deploy this, and then assign permissions to users (Moderator etc)
as well as have the ability to disable accounts etc.

Or is there a way to use ASP.Net Website Administration Tool from a live website?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: why don't you create your own database ?

Comment: Yeah I had considered it, but was hoping there would be an easier way to manage users, rather than make changes to the registration/login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use server side code to deal with them by using Membership. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When you open the solution in Visual Studio, the DB should show up in your App_Data folder.  If it's not there, make sure show all files is checked.  You should be able to double click it to open up the database in Server Explorer and edit the tables directly

Comment: Yes its definitely in the App_Data, Although this method wont help me when its being stored on the server. As I will need to be able to manage new users, and assign moderator role to a select few.

Answer (score 1):

As Maysam points out, you should not modify these things directly via any SQL tool but rather use the Membership API. A quick and easy way to get there would be the [MVC Membership Starter Kit](https://github.com/TroyGoode/MembershipStarterKit).

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/building-an-interface-to-select-one-user-account-from-many-cs) will help you start with creating an interface for user management tasks on your web-site.

With [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx) tutorial you can feature your user management further.